# How to make Activity Indicator start animating right away

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In my code I'm trying to make the activity indicator start animating RIGTH away, but for some reason, when I click my button it first goes to the next page. When I go back to the previous page, it then shows the indicator spinning. This is driving me crazy. Here is my code in the viewdidLoad to make it hidden when you first go to the page:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
searchedItem.delegate = self;
activityInd.hidden = YES;

}
```

And here is my other code for checking if my button is in the selected mode so that I can start the animation:

```
-(IBAction)ClickBtn:(UIButton *)sender
{
sender.selected  = ! sender.selected;

if (sender.selected)
{
    activityInd.hidden = NO;
    [activityInd startAnimating];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@" Selected");
}
}
```

I'm really not sure why it's waiting for me to first leave the page and THEN come BACK to it to make it start spinning.

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Comment: You call Webservice on Button Event

Comment: Is the indicator's superview is the next page? If its superview is current page, you can see the indicator only on the current page.

Comment: how do i know if its superview is on the next page or current one?

Comment: You hidden activityInd.hidden = YES; in ViewWillApper method . Not ViewDidLoad

Comment: If you added the indicator as subview on current view, the indicator's superview is current view. If you want see the indicator on next view, you must add subview on next view.

Comment: i for sure want to see the indicator on the current view, so i think ill add the subview to this view...although I'm pretty sure by default it is a subview of the current view

Answer (score 0):

I usually make the indicator control class as a singleton, and make the indicator's superview app delegate's window. Whenever you show the indicator, the indicator will be on key window.

```
@interface Indicator : UIActivityIndicatorView
+ (void)show;
+ (void)hide;
@end

@implementation Indicator

+ (Indicator *)shared
{
    static Indicator *indicator;
    if(indicator == nil)
    {
        indicator = [[Indicator alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        [indicator setCenter:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].center];
    }
    return indicator;
}

+ (void)show
{
    UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    [keyWindow addSubview:[Indicator shared]];
    [[Indicator shared] startAnimating];
}

+ (void)hide
{
    [[Indicator shared] removeFromSuperview];
    [[Indicator shared] stopAnimating];
}

@end
```

Like this. It's just sample I just coded. Wherever you want to show indicator, [Indicator show] will make thing happen.

Comment: how do i do that in my project?

Comment: do i make my activityIndicator object's custom class "Indicator"?

Comment: You don't have to. The code I added is just an example of indicator wherever can be used. The simplest answer for your question is add the indicator on your next page(view).

Answer (score 0):

In your IBaction method add,

```
    activityInd.hidden = NO;
    [activityInd startAnimating];

[self performSelector:@selector(goToNextPage) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```

Then,

add this method below.

```
- (void) goToNextPage
{
    //call your second page here

}
```

Comment: for some reason with this code RIGHT BEFORE i transition to the next view i get a small glimpse of the indicator. Even when i set the delay to 0.1....It seems nothing is working

Comment: instead of goToNextPage, I'm using prepareForSegue..is that ok?

Comment: just write your code in goToNextPage method. it should be ok

Comment: i got errors so i changed it to - (void) goToNextPage:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

Comment: can u tell how r u going to write prepareforseque method in ibaction method

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
        searchedItem.delegate = self;
        activityInd.hidden = YES;


    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Comment: i still get the same issue. I can see the spinner, but just barely a second before it transitions to the next page

Comment: @doc92606 put also  activityInd.hidesWhenStopped = YES;

Comment: - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{activityInd.hidden = YES;
 [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

Comment: I'm getting same issues

Comment: activityInd.hidden = YES;
    [activityInd stopAnimating];

Answer (score -1):

```
    {
            spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]  initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
                spinner.frame = CGRectMake(40, 90, 24, 24);
                [self.view addSubview:spinner];

                [spinner setHidden:YES];

            UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 30.0, 49.0);
            btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            [self.view addSubview:btn];
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(ClickBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

-(IBAction)ClickBtn:(UIButton *)sender
{
    sender.selected  = ! sender.selected;

    if (sender.selected)
    {
        spinner.hidden = NO;
        [spinner startAnimating];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@" Selected");
    }
}
```